# The number of partitioning of $\{1,\dots,10\}$ into $4$ groups such that no group has $1$ member

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Question :

How many ways can we partition $\{1,\dots,10\}$ into $4$ groups such that no group has just $1$ member?

Note 1 : This problem **should** be solved using **inclusion-exclusion principle**.

Note 2 : Should  i consider the opposite case? What is it ? I mean, if "no group has just $1$ member" is false, then what is the other case? Should i consider that one time, one set has $1$ member , the other time, $2$ sets have $1$ member, the last time, $3$ sets have one member and the other one has $9$ members?

Comment: I would interprete : "No group is allowed to have exactly one member" In other words : "Every group must have at least $2$ members" (because "empty groups" are surely not considered to be a group)

Comment: Are the groups labeled or unlabeled?

Comment: @bof i think they're not... because the question doesn't mention anything about labels

Comment: @Peter yes you're right ...

Comment: @bof why? what's the difference ?

Comment: @bof all you have to do is divide by $24$ to pass from one case to the other right? Since the number of blocks is fixed.

Comment: The difference between labeled and unlabelled groups is this (illustrated using an easier example): The number of ways to partition $\{1,2,3\}$ into two unlabelled groups is $3$ (you basically have to decide which number is alone). Into labeled groups, the answer is $6$ (you have to decide whether the number that is alone goes into group A or group B)

Comment: @Arthur so, does this question have an answer?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every group must have at least $2$ members and Let the groups be $G1$ , $G2$ , $G3$ and $G4$

I can write as

$G1 + G2 + G3 + G4 = 10$ for $G(i) >= 0$,

But as the constraint is there that every group must have atleast 2 numbers, then I can modify the above equation as

$G1 + G2 + G3 + G4 = 2$ for every $G(i) >= 2$

This is a simple stars and bars problem with total number of ways = $C(5,2)$